# How to set ngModel for input fields inside dynamic directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a directive `<stu-directive>` which is dynamically added every time a button is clicked. I have input fields in the directive which I want to attach to the object in html's controller(`CertObj`) as a property along with other properties from the html's input fields(I mean the part outside directive).

In my html which uses the directive, I used `ng-repeat` with an array that has nothing but incremented values. When button is clicked I push a value into array so that new directive is added inside `ng-repeat`.

The `certObj` is an object in the html's controller. I want to attach the values of input fields of all dynamically added directives to the object. I have an array `student:[]` in the `certObj` along with other properties. I use this array `student` to store objects from the directives `student:[{inputDatafromdirective},{inputDatafromdirective}]`.

But the `student` array has only one object(of the last directive). Every directive is supposed to push its input field values to `student` array of `certObj`object. But `certObj` has only one `{datafromlastdirective}`.

The html that uses the `<stu-directive>` with `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="certFull" id="">

   <stu-directive ng-transclude ng-repeat="direc in direcCountArray" obj=certObj.student[direc] >
   <!--<span>{{direc}}</span>-->

   <div class="col-md-6">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign plus" ng-click="addDirective()"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      Add another student
   </div>
</div>
```

The `stu-directive`'s html:

```
<div  ng-transclude class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="studentNameId">Student name</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="certObj.student[direc].studentName"> <!--direc is undefined -->
         <option>Stu1</option>
         <option>Stu2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6"><label for="studentNameId">Student mark</label></div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="certObj.student[direc].studentMark" placeholder="Student mark" />
   </div>
</div>
```

The directive :

```
    uiRouteApp.directive('stuDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            certObj: '=obj' //certObj to access the student array
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'htmlFiles/stuDirective.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {

            $scope.$watch("certObj.student[direc].studentMark", function (newval, oldval) {
              $scope.certObj.student.push({"studentMark":newval, "studentName" :$scope.studentName});

            })
            $scope.$watch("certObj.student.studentName", function (newval, oldval) {

            })
        }],
     }
})
```

The controller:

```
    uiRouteApp.controller('certController', function ($scope, $state, $compile) {
    $scope.showErrorMessage = false;
    $scope.certObj = {
        student: []
    };
    $scope.certObjArr = [];
    $scope.addDirective = function () {
        $scope.countForArray++;
        $scope.direcCountArray.push($scope.direcCountArray.length);
    }
});
```

Comment: It *feels like* you are approaching this the wrong way.  Instead of passing the **entire** `certObj` to each instance of the directive, you should only pass the `certObj.student` object for each iteration.  Then your directive can refer to `student.studentMark` directly in it's bindings.

Comment: @Claies. um, I think I have passed only `certObj.student`. Look at the `ng-repeat` line(`obj=certObj.student[direc]`). If this is not what you meant, please explain.

Comment: Well this seems to be part of the problem.  your `stuDirective` has a scope that has `certObj: '=obj'`, and you are still trying to refer to `certObj.student`, but you are *passing* `obj=certObj.student[direc]` in, meaning that in the directive, `certObj == certObj.student[direc]`, which definitely wouldn't have a `student` array in it....

Comment: @Claies but in the directive's template html, I've done `ng-model="certObj.student[direc].studentName"` which is probably not working because `direc` is undefined in there

Comment: what you should try, instead, is `student: '=obj'` in the directive scope, and then `ng-model="student.studentName"`in the HTML.

Comment: @Claies um, you're right. I will have to check when I go back tomorrow. thanks. Also I feel that this part `ng-model="certObj.student[direc].studentName"` inside the directive is not right. Can you please explain in an answer what I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive, you are creating a *new, isolated scope*.  Even though the properties are named the same, they aren't references to the same object.  This has created a bit of confusion, because you are passing an object into your directive and giving it a different name, confusing it's purpose.

In your main HTML file, your directive looks like `<stu-directive ng-transclude ng-repeat="direc in direcCountArray" obj=certObj.student[direc] >`.  This will take whatever the value of `certObj.student[direc]` is and store it in `obj`.

In the directive's `scope` you have `certObj: '=obj'`.  This will take whatever the value in `obj` is, and store it in `certObj`.  The fact that you used the name `certObj` here creates a point of confusion, since you didn't pass a `certObj` in, you passed a child of `certObj` in, but are assigning it a name that doesn't make that clear.

In your HTML for the directive, you have `ng-model="certObj.student[direc].studentName"`.  This is a product of the confusion previously mentioned, as in the context of the directive, `certObj` isn't a `certObj` but a child element already.  Thus, `certObj.student` doesn't really exist here, and `direc` is `undefined` here anyway.

To correct this, start from the directive's scope, and refer to the object with a name that clearly shows what is being passed in, i.e. `thisStudent: '=obj'`.  You know that for each copy of the directive, it is getting a single student, so `thisStudent` makes sense.

Now, in your directive's HTML, it's clear what you are looking for.  `ng-model="thisStudent.studentName"`.